# Getting two completely different columns in one query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm developping an asp.net project. I need to filter database with two different conditions and show each in a pie chart. So i need to get two columns in one query.

Column 1 :

```
select COUNT (*) 'OAS' from atmterminalfile (nolock) where Atstatu='2' and atlinestat ='1'
```

Column 2 :

```
select COUNT (*) 'OFS'  from atmterminalfile (nolock) where Atstatu='2' and atlinestat ='2'
```

I searched many solutions, i tried UNION but result was this

```
|      OAS       |
|----------------|
| Column 1 Count |
| Column 2 Count |
```

i just need this.

```
|      OAS         |        OFS       |
---------------------------------------
| Column 1 Count   |  Column 2 Count  |
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select sum(case when atlinestat = 1 then 1 else 0 end) 'OAS',
       sum(case when atlinestat = 2 then 1 else 0 end) 'OFS' 
from atmterminalfile (nolock) 
where Atstatu='2' 
and atlinestat in (1,2)
```

Comment: how about speeding it up by adding: and atlinestat in (1,2)

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted answer will work, this looks like a prime case for a `PIVOT` query.

```
select * 
from atmterminalfile 
pivot (count(id) for atlinestat in ([1],[2])) p
```